# MongoDB Atlas: cluster paused and Authentication failed

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am back working on a project I didn't touch for monthes.
On mongoDb Atlas I have this message :

[image]

As you can see, the Resume button is disabled so I cannot click it.

When I try to connect to mongo through either NodeJs, Mongo Compass or mongosh, i get the same error over and over :

> bad auth : Authentication failed.

- I am not including the <> in the connection string password.
- I tried to change my user password and user the new one.
- I tried to create a new user for the database and use this user/password.
- I am not using the account password (I use the one created with the db user)
- I use the exact same connection string given in the "connect" button in mongo atlas and I replace the "<password>" field with my user's password.

But I always have this error :

> bad auth : Authentication failed.

I have another cluster which was paused too. But for this second one the resume button was enabled and I can connect the databases without any error.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If the cluster tier is anything other than an M0 you can click the support link in Atlas and ask for help within the MongoDB ecosystem.

Comment: The cluster is M0

Comment: Assuming this is a development effort, you might be able to terminate the cluster, then create a new one...

Comment: Yes i can. Other clusters work, but the problem is I cannot transfer my data from the old one to the new one since I cant access it.